# Import color sceme to intellij on mac

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, ide, settings, preferences

I have a color scheme file in an XML format. I can't find how to import it into intellij and make it one of my color templates.

I try to do it on mac (libraries and files are different than linux or windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the XML color scheme file in one of this folders depending on your version of IntelliJ

#### Mac OS X

```
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/colors (IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate Edition)
~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC12/colors (IntelliJ IDEA 12 Community Edition),
~/Library/Preferences/WebIDE50/colors (PHPStorm 5.0).
```

#### Windows

```
Documents and Settings/<user>/.IdeaIC12/config/colors (IntelliJ IDEA 12 Community Edition)
```

[Source](https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized/blob/master/README.md)